# Connect to external OIDC endpoints via proxy

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, proxy

A JWT token needs to be validated on the backend. Backend .NET 6 WEB API code uses JWT Bearer authentication in `Program.cs` file  as below for validating the token. It works fine with localhost. I want to understand how to set the value for `options.Authority` , `options.MetadataAddress` and `var jwks` in below code when I would need to use proxy on the server and uncomment the two lines in `HttpClientHander`.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt => {
           opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           opt.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;    })
              .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                   {
                       HttpClientHandler handler = new()
                       {
                           //Proxy = new WebProxy(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("proxyServer"), 3128),
                           //UseProxy = true
                       };
                       HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
                       var clientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientId");
                       var clientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientSecret");
                       client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("BaseAddress"));
                       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
                       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + Convert.ToBase64String(
                                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                           $"{clientId}:{clientSecret}")));
               
                       options.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DiscoveryWellKnownOpenIdConfigurationURL");
                       options.MetadataAddress = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DiscoveryWellKnownOpenIdConfigurationMetaDataURL");
                       var jwks = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwksURL");
               
                       var key = jwks.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                       var signingKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(key));
               
                       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                       {
                           ValidateIssuer = true,
                           ValidateAudience = true,
                           ValidateLifetime = true,
                           RequireExpirationTime = true,
                           ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ValidIssuer"),
                           ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClientId"),
                           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(signingKey),
                       };
                   });
           builder.Services.AddCors(options =>    {
           options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                             policy =>
                             {
                                 policy.WithOrigins(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("WebAppBaseAddress"),
                                                     builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("OIDCEndPointBaseAddress"));
                             });    });
```

Changed `.AddJwtBearer` method to async and tried something like below. But that doesn't seem right as I am getting 503 'Service Unavailable' error when deploying the code.

```
HttpRequestMessage request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DiscoveryWellKnownOpenIdConfigurationURL"));
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage1 =  client.Send(request1);
    HttpContent content1 = responseMessage1.Content;
    options.Authority = await content1.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
HttpRequestMessage request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DiscoveryWellKnownOpenIdConfigurationMetaDataURL"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage2 = client.Send(request2);
            HttpContent content2 = responseMessage2.Content;
            options.MetadataAddress = await content2.ReadAsStringAsync();
    
HttpRequestMessage request3 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwksURL"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage3 = client.Send(request3);
            HttpContent content3 = responseMessage3.Content;
            var jwks = await content3.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: You will find the `Web.config` files in the deployed application. Change the `stdoutLogEnabled` value to `true` and run the application. Log file will be created with the detailed error in the `C:\home\LogFiles>` folder.

Comment: Try to remote debug the application.You can find out the exact line where the actual issue is.

Comment: ok, I could fix this. The error was because of incorrect proxy server name. Thanks for your comments.